# Wireshark: Filtering out uninteresting zigbee messages

Tags: wireshark, zigbee

Are there any Wireshark gurus?

I am debugging an issue on my home Zigbee network. I have a sniffer dongle and I can catch all the packets transmitted. Since my network has ~40 devices, the air is quite cluttered with packets I am not really interested in. I am looking for a ways to filter uninteresting messages

[image]

Questions:

1. Is there a way to filter out messages related to IEEE protocol (various Data Requests, and Acks), while leaving only upper layer messages (Zigbee, Zigbee HA)?
2. Is there a way to assign human readable labels for the devices on the network? e.g. 'Coordinator' instead of 0x0000, or 'Light Switch' instead of '0xc83a'?

Answer (score 1):

1. I would propose making **your own filters** *(whoah, relax, we are not animals, we do this the smart way)* ... go to `Statistics > Protocol Hierarchy`, the panel should show you all the traffic by protocols. Then just identify which protocols you do not want to see, mark them (one by one), right-click and `Prepare as Filter > ...and not Selected` (to prepare a filter to exclude the highlighted protocol). Sadly wireshark does not allow you to select multiple protocols to exclude at once. After this simply [save your filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDefineFilterSection.html) and reuse it as much as you like
2. What you are trying to do is [Name resolution](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvNameResolutionSection.html). This is done via [configuration files](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAppFilesConfigurationSection.html), more specifically `ethers` and `hosts`